# how to check that one column in database has empty value

Tags: mysql, jsp

I have a table application in database which has some columns naming leaveid, leavetype, nofdaysand and some many more.q is the logical name of a selected textfield  option.  If some user has no data in `nofdays` then how can I determine that? I am using this but it is not working:

```
String q = request.getParameter("q");
ResultSet r = smt.executeQuery(
    "select leaveid ,leavetype,sum(nofdays) as nofdays from application where (name= '"
        + session.getAttribute("userid") + "' and leavetype='" + q
        + "') group by leavetype" );

while (r.next()) {
    nofdays = r.getInt("nofdays");
    if (nofdays == 0) {
        if (q.equals("SL")) {
            balleave = 12 - nofdays;
            out.print(balleave);
        }
    }
```

I want to get the value in (balleave=12).  How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit unclear what you're asking, but I *think* what you're struggling with is cases where your table contains zero rows having the selected user ID and `leavetype` "SR".  In such cases, it seems you want to compute `balleave` as 12.  Supposing that I have interpreted you correctly, there are several problems with both your approach and your specific code.

The most fundamental problem with the approach is that your query does not return any rows corresponding to the condition you want to detect.  This is natural because an aggregate query such as yours aggregates only *existing* data.  The easiest way to approach this problem is probably to just set a default value (i.e. 12) to use when no other result is indicated.

Now, your query and Java code are so overcomplicated for the task you describe that I'm inclined to think you have some larger reason for the structure you have chosen.  Since you have not disclosed such a thing, however, I cannot suggest how to integrate a working approach into it.  Instead, here's a standalone version:

```
int balleave = 12;  // This value will stick if there is no data
String q = request.getParameter("q");

if ("SR".equals(q)) {
    PreparedStatement stmt = connection.prepareStatement(
        "select sum(nofdays) as nofdays from application where name = ? and leavetype= 'SR'");

    try {
        stmt.setString(1, session.getAttribute("userid"));

        ResultSet r = stmt.executeQuery();

        try {
            if (r.next()) {
                balleave -= r.getInt("nofdays");
            }
        } finally {
            r.close();
        }
    } finally {
        stmt.close();
    }
}
```

Note that no loop is required, because the result set will contain at most one row.  This is also true of your original code.  Note, too, that it very unsafe to construct SQL statements by concatenating input values with string literals.  When you want to execute a statement that is parameterized by variable input values, use a `PreparedStatement`.  *Especially so* when any of the parameters is drawn from user input.

Additionally, you were setting `balleave` only in the event that the user specified `q` as "SR".  If that's the only objective then you don't need to perform any query at all when the user specifies some other value of `q` -- in that case, you know in advance that you would not get a result that serves the purpose.